# HTML/JS: Turn a range control into a number input and back

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface, slider

With HTML/JS, I'd love to create a UI control for tweaking numbers.

### Requirements

I'd love to support a coarse-vs.-fine scheme, i.e., reuse the space of a range control for a number input, so that workflow for tweaking a number would look like this:

- Drag the slider to enter the rough zone;
- Double-click the slider and see the input control in place while the range turns invisible;
- Enter the accurate number;
- Press Escape on keyboard and see the range control again, and the input becomes invisible.

Would this be possible? If so, I need some pointers how to do this. Would it be an overlay or remove/add/refresh cycles? I honestly have no idea how.

Answer (score 1):

This should be possible by setting the `value` of the range control directly.

It could be as simple as listening for mouse events on the slider, hooking into one of these, showing a modal that has one input prefilled to the existing value on the slider, allowing the user to change the value directly.

Upon 'submitting' this modal update the value of the slider i.e `document.getElementById("slider").value = 123;`